# Chrome renders font icon correctly on one part of page, but not another

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, webfonts

I'm having the weirdest issue and can't track it down. In Chrome only, on the title of this page, a FontAwesome "lock" icon inserted using a CSS pseudo-element is appearing as a square. Later down the page using the exact same CSS the lock icon is correctly displayed. Again, only in Chrome - the lock icon appears correctly everywhere in Firefox, IE and Edge (haven't yet tested in Safari).

https://thirdlamardev.wpengine.com/news/this-is-3rd-lamar/

This is the SCSS being used everywhere the lock icon should appear:

```
.rcp-is-restricted .entry-title {
    position:relative;
    padding-left: 1em;

    &::before {
        display:inline-block;
        position:absolute;
        font-size:.8em;
        font-weight:300 !important;
        font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro" !important;
        content:"\f30d"; 
        color:black;
        left:0;
        top:.1em;
    }
}
```

Any ideas would be most welcome. Thanks!

Comment: remove `display:inline-block` and change  the position from `absolute` to `relative`. it will display the lock icon in chrome.

Comment: Check "entry-header" from "entry-header entry-header-standard entry-header-thumbnail". Once you remove this particular class, the lock appears. Probably some CSS property is being affected by this class.

Comment: another way: change display into grid

Comment: Additionally, display: inline-flex|flex|inline-grid|inline-table works too

Comment: Thanks! All of your suggestions helped.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, don't have enough reputation to add a comment... it works fine outside of the "post-header-inner" class container

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions from the commenters ( @VigneshA @KK @WoAiNii ) all helped, thanks! After experimenting a combo of `position:absolute` and `display:inline-flex` seems to work best cross-browser:

```
.rcp-is-restricted .entry-title {
    position:relative;
    padding-left:.5em;

    &::before {
        position:absolute;
        display:inline-flex;
        font-size:.7em;
        font-weight:300 !important;
        font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro" !important;
        content:"\f30d"; 
        color:black;
        left:-.5em;
        top:.3em;
    }
}
```